# ngx-perfect-scrollbar is not working

Tags: angular

I want to include `perfect-scrollbar` in my project so I installed and included it in my project as demonstrated below.

But this error is displaying when I run the project:

**app.module**

```
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
    import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
const PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
suppressScrollX: true
};
@NgModule({
imports: [
PerfectScrollbarModule.forRoot(PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG)
]
```

but i keep getting this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>       at eval ()
>       at SystemJSLoader.__exec (http://localhost:47112/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1555:18)
>       at entry.execute

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this line:

```
'ngx-perfect-scrollbar': 'npm:ngx-perfect-scrollbar/bundles/ngx-perfect-scrollbar.umd.js'
```

to `systemjs.config.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to systemjs.config.js`and 'systemjs.debug.config.js'

'ngx-perfect-scrollbar': 'npm:ngx-perfect-scrollbar/bundles/ngx-perfect-scrollbar.umd.js'

Example:

```
(function(global){
System.config({
    paths: {
        'npm:' : 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
        app: 'app',
        ........
        ........

        'ngx-perfect-scrollbar': 'npm:ngx-perfect-scrollbar/bundles/ngx-perfect-scrollbar.umd.js'
    },
    packages: {
        ........
        ........

    }
});
})(this);
```